# How to do full vacuum on table with lot of dead rows w/o disk space?

Tags: postgresql, vacuum

Will  try to describe the problem:

We have a table "stories", current statistics:

total_relation_size: 188 GB

indexes only size: 52 GB

n_tup_del: 274299085

n_live_tup: 368846049

We currently have ~6 gigabytes left on our SSD.

Now we mounted another PC with ~190 gigabytes available, it's available as /dump folder.

How can we free up space?

Make pg_dump this table, then truncate it, and then restore? How safely is it?

Or we can somehow allow "vacuum full" to use mounted device (/dump) space to do? We understand that vacuum full will lock access.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Windows "share" is not safe storage for a database.

First, perform a backup.

Ignoring foreign key constraints, you could proceed as follows:

- Create a tablespace `dump` with location `/dump`.
- Create an empty copy there:

  ```
  CREATE TABLE copy (LIKE largetable) TABLESPACE dump;
  ```
- Run

  ```
  INSERT INTO copy SELECT * FROM largetable;
  ```
- Drop the large table.
- Move the new table to the default tablespace:

  ```
  ALTER TABLE copy SET TABLESPACE pg_default;

  ALTER TABLE copy RENAME TO largetable;
  ```
- Create indexes and constraints as appropriate.
- Clean up:

  ```
  DROP TABLESPACE dump;
  ```